# Qt OpenGL - Rotating with mouse drag

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qtopengl

I was going through the [Hello GL Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-hellogl.html) in the Qt documentation.

They have some code which helps in rotation the scene with mouse drag.

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    int dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
       setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
       setYRotation(yRot + 8 * dx);
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
       setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
       setZRotation(zRot + 8 * dx);
    }
   lastPos = event->pos();
}
```

And

```
 void GLWidget::setXRotation(int angle)
{
   qNormalizeAngle(angle);
   if (angle != xRot) {
       xRot = angle;
       emit xRotationChanged(angle);
       updateGL();
   }
}
```

I can understand that they are trying to calculate the change in x/y coordinates during the process of drag.

But how are they mapping it to rotating the scene ? Documentation lacks an explanation on what is being done.

Also, whats with these magic numbers `8` ?

Comment: Sometimes, or rather, very often, the numbers are derived empirically. Different numbers are tried and the best, the magic ones, picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is basically a pencil to draw stuff. There's no such thing like a scene. You, the programmer create a bunch of variables and then, when its time to draw something use those to move around the pencil that is OpenGL.

In your particular case there are some variables `xRot`, `yRot` and `zRot` that are used in the creation of the transformation chain that's applied for drawing the object. The actual drawing happens in `GLWidget::paintGL`; I annotated it for you:

```
 void GLWidget::paintGL()
 {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glLoadIdentity(); // reset transformation state
     glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0); // apply translation to transformation
     glRotatef(xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // apply rotation on x
     glRotatef(yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // apply rotation on x
     glRotatef(zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // apply rotation on x
     logo->draw(); // draw logo using the currently set transformation
 }
```

Comment: I understand this part. My particular concern was those special numbers appearing in the code. Why is the change in mouse positions being multiplied/divide by these magic numbers (8,16) ?

Comment: @AmitTomar: These are just (hardcoded) scaling factors. They have no special meaning other than give the interaction a certain "feel". In a more sophisticated implementation (say an arcball) the scaling may even depend on the position of the pointer relative to where the motion started.

Answer (score -1):

emit xRotationChanged(angle) - rotates your scene on x-axis

8 handles your mouse sensitivity